# I am trying to convert some vanilla JavaScript into jQuery. But all I every get returned is [object object]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a chatbot. In this function on my js page I am putting the users response into its own 'div' container and adding a time-stamp underneath it. I do it like this so that I can easily access the CSS selectors. All of this code was previously only vanilla JavaScript and worked wonderfully. After having converted it over to jQuery all I get displayed is [object Object]. I am extremely new to jQuery, so a lot of these concepts may have gone over head. Please help me out.

```
function addChatToChatBoxUser(userReply){

  const $chatBox =$("#messages")[0];

  var $timestamp2 = $("<div>").addClass("timestamp2");
  timestamp2.html(`${new Date()
      .toString()
      .split(" ")
      .slice(0,5)
      .join(" "));

  var $repliesContainer = $("<div>").addClass("chat-user-side").attr("id", 'userMessages');
  var $userDiv = $("<div>").addClass("guest response").attr("id", 'guest');
  userDiv.html(`${inputReply}`);

  $repliesContainer.append($userDiv);
  $repliesContainer.append($timestamp2);
  $chatBox.append($repliesContainer);
  $chatBox.scrollTop = $chatBox.scrollHeight - $chatBox.clientHeight; 
}
```

Comment: inputReply is the input that the guest/user logs to the chat box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `const $chatBox =$("#messages")[0];` will return the DOM node, and not the jQuery object.

So when you later do `$chatBox.append($repliesContainer);` it will use the [`.append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) of the actual node which will try to convert the `$repliesContainer` to a string (since it is not a node).

Use `$($chatBox).append($repliesContainer);` for the correct jQuery `.append`

Answer (score 0):

man sorry but is ur chatbot using vanilla js having like a array based one like one folder with all functions to import and another with the const for q and const for a
... pls respond cause i also need some help cause i also made one using vanilla and im a complete newbie to progarming as a whole....

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.